# "#Next" and "#Prev" functions of Tiny carousel not working in mvc project

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

**I have to use a simple content carousel in my project..Using jquery 2.1.3....**
**Before that i used jquery content carousel but it was not responsive so i was looking for simple responsive carousel and find :[Tiny Carousel](http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/responsive/)**

**Now i have put its .js and .css files in Bundles.config as can be seen :**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/euro/js").
Include("~/Scripts/euro/*.js", "~/Scripts/euro/jquery.tinycarousel.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/euro/css").
Include("~/Content/euro/*.css", "~/Content/euro/tinycarousel.css"));
```

**And In View :**

```
 <div id="slider1">
        <a class="buttons prev" href="#">&#60;</a>
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">
                <li><img src="~/images/contact.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/contact.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/contact.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/contact.png" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="buttons next" href="#">&#62;</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#slider1').tinycarousel();
        });
    </script>
```

**Picture:**
[image]

**The problem is that the "prev" and "next" controls not working and also full images are not being displayed**

May be its the old/new jquery problem...Please if someone help...
    Or Can i check the scripts or css file problems in firebug??

**Thanks for your time..**

Comment: Have you heard of **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**

Comment: thanks for reply,,, yes but i am no expert

Comment: No need of expertise!! You just need to copy and paste the demo code given there.. :)

Comment: my problem is due to invalid or un-ordered js file....i will try this slider too

Comment: Why I suggested this is you don't need to worry about anything as it provides various options to modify and meet your requirements!! moreover its responsive!!! :)

Comment: ok, i will let you know then you can post it as answer...Thanks for your help

Comment: Its ok!! Just try and let me know if any problem.. :)

Comment: i cant see the content carousel, image slider are there...

Comment: Visit **[this link](http://cssslider.com/bootstrap-carousel-8.html)**

Comment: please see this link...http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/responsive/

Comment: Oh you want this type of carousel.. Ok.. Then check if you have any console errors in your browser with tiny carousel??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao you can post the bootstrap help as answer..... i forgot to tell you back when i finished my implementation after 6 days....it was bootstrap 3 version problem with jquery versions.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap carousel with bit modifications to the existing template of bootstrap. Bootstrap moves each `.item` element, so just place multiple images inside each `.item` which will give you the nearly desired result.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/dozrmR)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
        <p>Responsive Moving Box Carousel Demo</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
        </div>

        <div class="control-box">                            
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
        </div><!-- /.control-box -->   

    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.span12 -->          
</div><!-- /.row --> 
</div><!-- /.container -->
```